# I have two optional parameter second parametere have value and first parameter is empty so how to get second parameter value in controller

Tags: laravel, routes

I have route like **colleges/colleges-in-{area?}-{cities?}-india**. 
like **colleges/colleges-in-virar,thane-maharastra-india**. if i pass cities only so can i get cities in controller

In Controller :

$filter_cities = $request->route('area');
$filter_cities = $request->route('cities');

if i pass citiess then it pass in first parameter

Answer (score 1):

You can set variable in your route:

```
Route::get('colleges/{area}/{city}', 'Controller@myFunction');
```

In your controller

```
public function myFunction(Request $request)
{
  $area = $request->area;
  $city = $request->city;
}
```

Read documentation here: https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/routing